# Android Layout not initialising

Tags: android, layout

So this is my main layout and I want to add items programmatically as they will be dynamic.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/mainlayout" >
</LinearLayout>
```

The problem is, when I look for the LinearLayout with;

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainlayout);
```

Immediately after `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` it returns `null`. Even if I wait until `onStart()` or `onResume()`, it doesn't seem to be there. Any suggestions as to why this might be the case?

Comment: make sure u are using `setContentView(R.layout.layoutname); `in Activity on create method  before finding views

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**-** Immediately **after** `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)` you should use `setContentView(R.layout.youLayout)`.

**-** Its **only after** the `setContentView()` method, one can assign ids to the `Views`, cause till then the `Views` **aren't initialized**.

Comment: OK, but the ID is assigned in the XML which should be initialised during super.onCreate() shouldn't it? I thought that was the whole idea. If I put a button in that XML it will appear without me having to manually program it in and I would immediately be able to access it...

Comment: @FizzBuzz : **"...the ID is assigned in the XML which should be initialised during super.onCreate() shouldn't it?"** - No! Calling `super.onCreate(...)` has no effect on the layout. That's the whole point of using `setContentView(...)`, it inflates the XML layout file and until you have an inflated `View` of some sort you won't be able to get a reference to any part of it. That's exactly what Kumar Vivek Mitra has explained in the answer.

Comment: OK, thanks. I understand, I think I might have accidentally removed that line when trying to get something else to work -_-

Comment: @FizzBuzz you are welcome, and Squonk thanks for explaining the my answer to OP